# Did we able to solve your problems / Were we able to solve your problems

Tags: word-choice, questions, auxiliary-verbs

"Did we able to solve your problems?"

"Were we able to solve your problems?"

Here "Did" and "Were" have replaced each other, do they both say and mean the same?

Answer (score 3):

The first sentence is incorrect.  It should be:

"Did we solve your problems"

"Were we able to solve your problems" is correct though.

Good reference (albeit old) BBC page: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv196.shtml

Comment: Thanks for clearing it. Can you explain a little bit, why we can't use "Did we able to solve".

Comment: @arm It's because *able* is an adjective. We don't say, "He happy" or "He does happy"; we say "He is happy." Likewise, we don't say, "We did able to solve ..." or "Did we able to solve ...?", but we say, "We were able to solve ..." or "Were we able to solve ...?".

Answer (score 1):

You can't use "did" because the standard structure is "be able to do something". So, according to your subject, the verb "be" changes as well.